How to override OnFilterTouchEventForSecurity() in .NET MAUI Android
In Xamarin.Forms I was able to override OnFilterTouchEventForSecurity() by subclassing Content Page with PageRenderer. I want to achieve the same in MAUI but I have not been able to find this override method when I am subclassing content page with PageHandler. Can anyone please help me with this?
Xamarin Forms:
    public override bool OnFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent e)
    { }

.NET MAUI:
I am able to access this inside ConnectHandler as platformView.OnFilterTouchEventForSecurity , but I am not sure how can I use it here.
    protected override void ConnectHandler(ContentViewGroup platformView)
    {
       base.ConnectHandler(platformView);   
    }


You can also refer to the official doc: Create a custom control using handlers.

You can refer to the following code:
Create a custom page:
public class TestPage : ViewGroup
{
  public TestPage (Context? context) : base (context) {}

  public override boolOnFilterTouchEventForSecurity (MotionEvent? e)
  {
    return base.OnFilterTouchEventForSecurity (e);
  }

  protected override void OnLayout (bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
  {
    //You need to modify your layout
    var content = GetChildAt (0);
    if (content?.Visibility != ViewStates.Gone)
    {
        content?.Layout (0, 0, content.MeasuredWidth, content.MeasuredHeight);
    }  
    //....  
    
  }
}

Declare a handler:
public class MyPageHandler : ViewHandler<ContentPage, TestPage>
{
    public static IPropertyMapper<ContentPage, MyPageHandler> PropertyMapper = 
    new PropertyMapper<ContentPage, MyPageHandler>(ViewHandler.ViewMapper);
    
    public MyPageHandler() : base(PropertyMapper)
    {
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(TestPage platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    }

   protected override TestPage CreatePlatformView() => new TestPage(Context);
}

Add it in MauiProgram:
{
  public static MauiApp
  CreateMauiApp()
  {
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
        .ConfigureFonts (fonts => {
          fonts.AddFont ("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
          fonts.AddFont ("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        })
        .ConfigureMauiHandlers (handlers => {

#if ANDROID
          handlers.AddHandler<ContentPage, MyPageHandler>();
#endif

        });

#if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

    return builder.Build();
  }
}

And here is the effect. But this requires you to set up the layout. You can check this case: Correctly layout children with onLayout in Custom ViewGroup.
